# File's Owner is not visible

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I am starting with Xcode and I am already having a very basic problem. My File Owner's icon is not visible.

How can I make it visible?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your entire Xcode window?

Answer (score 0):

If you see a yellow cube in the left column of the editor while viewing a nib, that's the file's owner.

[image]

You may need to click on the arrow button at the bottom left of the editor to expand the column that shows the object hierarchy.

[image]

If you can't see the file's owner icon, I would expect that you are not editing a nib.

Comment: I am in MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard and I can't see any "File's Owner". I can see my apps interface. In my version I have 3 icons on the bottom of my 'iPhone': View Controler, First Responder and Exit.

Comment: I am using XCode 4.6.2